# express nodejs body is empty after post request

Tags: node.js, express, post

I have tried all out there but still the post request is giving me an empty. I checked in browser and also in postman the values are sent via the payload, but when getting via the router post, req.body is empty

main

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors");
// var bodyParser = require("body-parser");   body parser also didnt work

const app = express();
// app.use(
//   bodyParser.urlencoded({
//     extended: true,
//   })
// );
// app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));  // interchanged this below express.json didnt work
app.use(express.json());


const PORT = 3009;

// import routes
const router = require("./routes/route");
app.use("/api", router);


// connect mongo start
const uri =
  "mongodb+srv://adminuser:password@cluster0.gtkdj.mongodb.net/mydb?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

const options = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
};

mongoose.connect(uri, options);

const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
db.once("open", function () {
  console.log("Mongo Connected");
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("Port is connected at ", PORT);
});
```

model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const dataSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
  },
});

const dataModel = mongoose.model("data", dataSchema);

module.exports = dataModel;
```

routes

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const dataModel = require("../model/schema");

router.post("/new_items", (req, res) => {
  const data = new dataModel({
    name: req.body.name,
  });
  console.log(data, req.body);
  data
    .save()
    .then((item) => res.send(item))
    .catch((err) => res.status(400).send(err));
});
```

console output { _id: 6022f0c0b3dd8f2sdc5302f9 } {}

The req body is empty. Please help me on this. Thanks

Comment: do you set `Content-Type` : `application/json` in header of request? can you show me the request in postman? take a screen shot from body and header form postman

Comment: Woh! Mohammad. After all the issue was that i didnt pass the header. It worked after passing the header as         headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        }

Answer (score 0):

The codes were correct. But, the post request header was not present. After passing the header, it worked as intended.

```
  await fetch("http://localhost:3009/api/new_items/", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json", // this was missing
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
  })
```